# Does writing LaTeX packages need moderation?

Tags: packages, package-writing

30 years ago LaTeX was quite compact and observable being. Nowdays, CTAN repository counts more than 4k LaTeX packages and their number continues growing so that it is absolutely impossible to observe most packages within a sigle book. This makes difficult for newcomers to learn LaTeX. Many packages are not compatible, many are sensitive to the order of loading, many packages do almost the same things. For example, there are 4 incompatible packages on CTAN which provide bibtex/biblatex styles for GOST, a Russian state standard of bibliographic description. Note that there should be only one state standard at any instant of time, otherwise it is not a standard.

I am afraid that my question will be voted down but I'll ask it:

**Does writing LaTeX packages need more strict moderation than now?** Can someone propose a mechanism of such a moderation.

Comment: Maybe a question for LaTeX meta ?

Comment: One standard can have many implementations, see C++.

Comment: I think moderating the writing of LaTeX packages goes against the spirit of LaTeX.  If you set up gatekeepers on what can and can't be submitted as a package, I believe you will end up with a sterile product... able to do certain "pre-approved" things, but unable to flexibly change with the needs of the user base.

Comment: CTAN is decented conceptiually from CPAN,
CPAN has over 128K Perl modules.

Comment: Isn’t that one reason why ConTeXt was created?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: moderation can be set in a form of recommendations for authors of new packages, eg: (1) Search CTAN for similar packages; (2) investigate those packages; (3) contact autours of those package and ask them to upgrade their packages; (4) upload your packages if eigther of the steps 1-3 fail.

Comment: @Laurent No, it's not a question about this site, so not really suitable for Meta.TeX.sx. On the other hand, it might be more suitable on a different platform, e.g. c.t.t.

Comment: @Oxinabox you have history backwards: we did ctan first and perl community copied us (with attribution:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Wow, you learn something knew everyday, thanks

Comment: Does this question have a definitive answer, that is not primarily opinion based?

Comment: @Oxinabox it has a definitive answer but unfortunately the system doesn't allow two letter answers:-)

Comment: I agree with @TorbjørnT. , this question is too much a discussion topic and too little a question whose answers can be evaluated as "correct-incorrect". Therefore it is IMHO not suitable for the site; it would better suit c.t.t. or LaTeX-community.

Comment: Ok, my Q assumes opinion-based answers. May I ask then 2 more Qs? 
1) Does LaTeX3 team has prevaling opinion-based answer on my Q? 
2) Where one can ask such sort of Qs? I don't know what is c.t.t.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Comp.Text.Tex

Answer (score 6):

i don't know about *needing* more strict moderation (all we do is check a package for internal consistency before installing on ctan).

however, if we were to go that way, we would need to find someone (or more than one person) who one could reasonably hope would carry the community with her/his views.

but i fear “closing the door” now would create chaos in processing bug-fix updates, etc.

so cataloguing is probably the way to go; the ctan catalogue tries not to make value judgements, but i see no difficulty in principle with creating a catalogue that does tell you that package *x* does the job while package *y* is difficult to use/doesn't do the job right/...